# C# Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Core.Exceptions.ServiceException' in mscorlib.dll

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I am creating the Microsoft Teams recording bot. and its successfully receiving the incoming call request but while answering the call it is throwing the exception i.e.

> Exception thrown:
> 'Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Core.Exceptions.ServiceException' in
> mscorlib.dll

When and the following message is being written in my log file.

> ERROR Caught an Exception running the task: Answering call 861f3e00-1d20-4334-848a-3786b081586c with scenario 5a356e88-bfea-4250-ad06-d2ababed3128.

could anyone help me in solving this problem.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? Is there any inner exception with more details?

Comment: yes I tried to debug but not able to find any details about it.

Comment: @user2250152 the only error description I am getting is the .dll name and the Error caught message inside the log file as mentioned above.

Comment: If its a Graph error then you might be getting the requestid, timestamp along in the response; share it.

Comment: @Dev  I am getting this inside my log file 

2020-12-01 23:33:45.5007 ERROR Caught an Exception running the task: Status Code: NotFound
Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Core.Exceptions.ServiceException: Code: 8522
Message: Call not found.
Scenario Id: cf9ffc0e-4d48-45f9-a8b6-cdf6ea7e40f9
Inner error:
 AdditionalData:
 date: 2020-12-01T18:33:44
 request-id: e3a0ffbb-456e-4aec-9a65-15e7e96700c9
 client-request-id: a73bfdc5-1a11-4759-8b2e-ab356a1822b6

Comment: (1) Have you created a call first? (2) Does the your/service reach the bot? (3) Have you added the certs, CNAME entries etc?

Comment: I remember a related one logged at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/issues/81. Have a look at it

Comment: @Dev yes i am getting the incoming call request, I have also registers the domain name on ngrok. plus i also have a wildcard ssl certificate mapping on the tcp link. When answering the incoming call request it throws this exception

Comment: @Dev one more thing, the application i am creating is a .net console application

Comment: Issue is now resolved. Thanks @Dev for your response.

Comment: Glad to hear that @MurtazaMultan. Yes ngrok is a better way to find out whats happening inside it. Just curious how the issue got resolved?

Comment: @Dev actually the problem was of the permissions. As being in the organization I was given a separate subscription and I was trying to communicate with the Microsoft teams of an organization which was out of my scope and permission.

That was i figured out and after getting the required permissions, I was able to join the call.

Comment: @Dev sorry to disturb you again, just want a little favor. my next target is to record the meeting. Could you please guide me how can I do that with the help of media streams. Actually I searched and found that there is OnAudioReceived and OnVideoReceived methods to listen audio and video changes. Is there any way to get both together not separately. Also will it record the screen sharing of different participants?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @MurtazaMultan. I will move this to answer. Consider upvoting it. So it can be useful to others as well. Also if you dont mind post the above query in new stackoverflowthread and update it here, i will answer there...

Comment: Sure @Dev. here is the link to the new query 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65123158/recording-microsoft-teams-session-audio-video-screen-sharing-using-a-bot

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with permissions. As being in the organization you're given a separate subscription. When you are trying to communicate with the Microsoft teams of an organization which was out of your scope and permission. After you figured it out and setting/getting the required permissions, you're able to join the call.

Comment: In my case, for some reason the bot user account in the AD on Azure was Disabled. I enabled it and the error went away.