# Recording Microsoft Teams Session (Audio/Video/Screen Sharing) using a bot

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am creating a bot that will record the live event of Microsoft Teams. It is a .NET console application. I just want to know is there any method through which I can record the live session of Microsoft Teams (Audio/Video/Screen Sharing) using single listener? there are individual methods like OnAudioReceived, OnVideoReceived but I am looking for a method that can get audio video in single stream.

Comment: Sorry @Murtaza i dont remember that i noticed a single method to get audio video in single stream.

Comment: @dev can you share that method. Any link or sample code.

Comment: Sorry i think you're mistaken. I said i dont remember a single method which does the both or not that i aware that exists. Being said that if you want Microsoft to implement such feature in future, then consider creating a user voice/feature request item at Microsoft User voice(https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359626) - so that they can consider implementing it.

Comment: The closest one i can remember is [this], but it's meant for GET(https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/36819112-ability-to-retrieve-a-meeting-chat-and-audio-video)

Comment: ok @dev Thank you for the response

Comment: Glad if it had helped @Murtaza. In case if you create the uservoice, feel free to share here. So  community members will be aware of it and they can consider upvoting it as well.

Comment: Let me move this to answer. Consider upvoting it; so it can be useful to others as well.

Comment: Sure @Dev. Well I will try to implement it in future. Due to tight bound deadline of this project, I need to work with the available APIs. Will surely consider it once I done with this. Thanks again for your help and active response. Highly appreciated.

Comment: @Dev, could you please look at this problem. If possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65158315/convert-byte-to-video-mp3-or-any-other-palyable-format

Answer (score 0):

- There is no single listener/method exists to record the live session of Microsoft Teams (Audio/Video/Screen Sharing). This looks to me "By design".
- Being said that if you want Microsoft to implement such feature in
  future, then consider creating a user voice/feature request item at
  [Microsoft User voice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359626) - so that they can consider implementing it. The [closest one i remember is this](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/36819112-ability-to-retrieve-a-meeting-chat-and-audio-video).